# trying to change inner html of h1 tag but js throwing an error

Tags: javascript, html

```
   the javascript below is the line 13 and the h1 is my html tag
```

index.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
at index.js:13

```
<h1 id="text">javascript practice</h1>

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'hey there';
```

Comment: Make sure your `<script>` comes after the h1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to sure, the Element mounted in DOM

you can use like this

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
     document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'hey there';
});
```

In this snippet , your code run when all of the nodes (elements) loaded

Comment: thanks this worked but the video i was watching the guy just did the same thing i did and it worked?

Comment: maybe <script> Tag comes at the end of <body> Tag

Comment: the js page is linked so i didnt put script tags i wrote on the js page

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a function for the JavaScript? That would fix the issue. A great example would be:

```
const h1 = document.getElementById('text');

h1.addEventListener('click', () => {
h1.innerHTML = <p>Hey There</p>
})
```

Comment: He just needed to render HTML to h1 tag when window loads. no need to add click event  on the h1